# trouble to connecting to remote file system using sshfs

Tags: linux, ssh, network-shares, sftp

I'm a first time user of sshfs, trying to use it to give myself access to a remote file system.

```
$ sudo sshfs username@servername.edu:/home/csg/username/low /local/servername
```

When I issue this command, everything seems to work fine, but I don't get any sort of directory access in my /local/servername folder. Anybody know what I need to do next? Or have some good documentation on how to use this?

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04.

Thanks!

Comment: did you add your username to the fuse group?

Comment: @john 'sudo' .. what more rights does he need?

Comment: @carl: what does 'mount | grep servername' give you? is it at least mounted correctly?

Comment: @akira, it returns nothing

Comment: then it looks like 'everything seems to work fine' is a false claim :) 'mount' should list all (including fused handled) mounted nodes. i would look into that problem first

Answer (score 4):

You have issued the sshfs command with sudo - which means the files mounted under /local/servername are only readable by root.

So you'll either need to do 'sudo bash' to get a root prompt which will allow you to browse it's content, or you need to do as John T suggested in the comments, and make sure your own user is a member of the 'fuse' group, and then NOT use the sudo prefix when issuing the sshfs command.

Note: Should you choose the latter option (and you should) you will find out that the mounted file system's contents are not visible to root either. FUSE mounted file systems are *very* user specific.

Comment: i dont think its a problem of "permissions" but rather a "nothing is mounted and thus nothing can be accessed" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your username to the group `fuse` like so:

```
sudo adduser YourUsernameHere fuse
```

that should make the files visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

By default fuse file systems are [only accessible to the user that mounted them](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=SshfsFaq#Mounting_as_root). By doing `sudo`, this is effectively the root user.
Try just mounting it as your user (without `sudo`) or with `-o allow_other` (but this needs to be enabled in `/etc/fuse.conf`).